# Como fazer um upload em php

Tags: php, upload

Bem, basicamente eu estou tentando fazer um upload de um arquivo mp3 para uma pasta que eu criei do servidor, porem eu ja fiz de tudo mesmo, e acabo sempre com o mesmo erro. Esse é o código:

```
<?php
    include("connectsql.php");
    isset($_GET ['mp3file']) ? $_GET['mp3file'] : '';
    $songname = $_GET['songname'];
    $query = "SELECT id FROM songs WHERE Song = '$songname'";
    $result = mysqli_query($link, $query) or die(mysqli_error($link));
    $uploaddir = 'http://localhost/sitededownload/musicas/';
    $uploadfile = $uploaddir . basename($_FILES['mp3file']["name"]);
    if($result){
        $nomemusica = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result);
    }

    echo "<pre>";
        if (move_uploaded_file($_FILES['mp3file']["name"], $uploadfile)) {
            echo "Arquivo válido e enviado com sucesso.\n";
        }else {
            echo "Possível ataque de upload de arquivo!\n";
        }


        PRINT_R($_FILES);

    echo "</pre>";
?>
```

e esse é o resultado do PRINT_R:

```
Possível ataque de upload de arquivo!
Array
(
    [mp3file] => Array
        (
            [name] => I Feel It Coming.mp3
            [type] => 
            [tmp_name] => 
            [error] => 1
            [size] => 0
        )

)
```

alguma solução?

Answer (score 0):

O valor `1` na variavel `error` indica o erro `UPLOAD_ERR_INI_SIZE`, todas constantes estão neste link: http://php.net/manual/en/features.file-upload.errors.php

Como numero deve ser comparado a uma constante, mas vamos falar do erro `UPLOAD_ERR_INI_SIZE`, isto indica que o arquivo é maior que o limite permitido no arquivo de configuração do seu servidor **php.ini**, se você tem permissão administrativa para editar este arquivo então procure a linha que contém `upload_max_filesize=`

Deve estar provavelmente com *2M*, que quer dizer que o limite do upload é de 2mb:

```
upload_max_filesize=2M
```

Altere para algo maior, como 16M (maior que isto só se for necessário mesmo, caso contrário prefira não usar valores muito grandes, pois isto consome muito do servidor):

```
upload_max_filesize=16M
```

Salve o arquivo e reinicie o seu servidor HTTP (deve ser Apache, Nginx ou LightTTPD).

Se não for possivel aumentar por diversos possiveis fatores, como alguma restrição da sua hospedagem então recomendo como alternativa dividir o arquivo e fazer o upload usando as APIs do JavaScript `XmlHttpRequest` e `FileReader`.

Outro detalhe importante citado pelo @RpgBoss é que esta linha esta errada:

```
 $uploaddir = 'http://localhost/sitededownload/musicas/';
```

O `move_uploaded_file` deve receber um caminho *fisico*, se for windows deve ser algo como:

```
 $uploaddir = 'c:/xampp/www/sitededownload/musicas/';
```

Se for unix-like talvez seja algo como:

```
 $uploaddir = '/etc/www/sitededownload/musicas/';
```

Comment: Essa linha está certa?
`$uploaddir = 'http://localhost/sitededownload/musicas/';`
Achei que tivesse que ser algo assim: `$uploaddir = 'sitededownload/musicas/`

Comment: @RpgBoss bem notado, este é outro erro, note que o valor de error ocorre antes de move_upload, pois esta função só move da pasta TMP do servidor para a pasta desejada, na verdade o upload já ocorre e falhou antes. +1 pro seu comentário.

Comment: obrigado pelas respostas gente, vou fazer tudo isso e volto aqui para contar o resultado, agradeço desde ja!!